# Installing a site from existing configuration

Tags: 8, configuration, installation

I tried importing a configuration after installing Drupal 8 using the standard installation profile but was getting into errors related to the installation profile being already present.

I need a clean drupal slate with only the configuration and no content.  Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Hey Binny, what errors are you talking about?

Comment: Installing a site from existing configuration is a core feature since Drupal 8.6, so you don't need to import configuration after installing. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2897299

Comment: @leymannx I got errors related to   The selected profile has a hook_install() implementation and therefore can not be installed from configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out we can do this by running the following drush command

```
drush site:install --existing-config
```

However you might encounter an error related to hook_install found in standard install profile. To mitigate that you would need to install this patch.

https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-11-27/2982052-22.patch

Comment: Exactly, the problem is you can't install from configuration if the sued profile needs a hook_install. For other visitors, the patch's issue is: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2982052

Comment: Where does the existing configuration come from? I don't see any way to specify a directory using the `--existing-config` argument.

Comment: It comes from $settings["config_sync_directory"] in settings.php. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2897299